# What is Object::nvim (Object#nvim) in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a fresh ruby-2.5.1 installed via rvm. I looked into rubydocs. The only gem that I have installed is irbtools. When I tried

> Object.new.methods.sort

I noticed I have some nvim method:

> :mvim, :nano, :nil?, :nvim, :object_id, :only_class_ancestors,

I tried looking for it on Google, official Ruby documentation sites, irbtools documentation and ri and found nothing. What does this method do?

I tried

> Object.new.method(:nvim).source_location

And got

> ["/home/igor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/interactive_editor-0.0.11/lib/interactive_editor.rb",
>   105]

Which is interactive_editor gem, but what does it do?

Comment: Don't know this one, but appears it might have something to do with VIM, the text editor? I am running on 2.4.4 on Windows ATM, and it is not present.

Comment: https://github.com/jberkel/interactive_editor – the gem lets you launch an editor from within irb.

Comment: When you installed `irbtools` that is definitely not the "only gem" (19 other gems are installed as dependencies [irbtools.gemspec](https://github.com/janlelis/irbtools/blob/master/irbtools.gemspec)) and `interactive_editor` happens to be one of them.